# CRM Dynamics How to set short list - long list relationship

Tags: list, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have 3 entities, one of them contains many records, the other two are lists of those records. My aim is to create long lists and a short lists of those candidates. I can create long lists of course with n-n relationship. I add records to the long list with "add existing record" button. But, I have to create the short lists which select their records from the items from specified long lists. User will first eliminate most of the records and add them to the long list, then eliminate those ones from the long list and add them to the shortlist.

To fully specify it:

- Record entity: `x1,x2,x3..............xn`
- Long List Entity: `LL1 (x1,x4,x7), LL2(x2,x10)` {sample}
- Short List Entity: `SL1 (x1,x7), SL2(x2)` {they have the records from the long lists, and when the records are entered, the only options are the records from the specified long lists.}

So, how can I make such a system work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create four entities LongList, ShortList, LongListMember, ShortListrMember

**LongList Entity attributes**

1) List Name

2) Any other information you want to store about the list.

**ShortList Entity attributes**

1) List Name

2) LongList - Lookup to related LongList record

3) Any other information you want to store about the list.

**LongListMember Entity attributes**

1) List Name - Lookup to LongList Entity

2) Member - Lookup to entity that you want to track in the list.

**ShortListMember Entity attributes**

1) List Name - Lookup to ShortList Entity

2) Member - Lookup to entity that you want to track in the list.

**Now to create a Long List**

1) Create an record of Entity LongList

2) For each of the records you want to track in the list, add a LongListMember record where

a) List Name field points to the new LongList record that you created

b) Member field points to the record you want to add to the list.

**Similarly, to create a ShortList**

1) Create an record of Entity ShortList

2) Set the Long List field to the related Long List record

3) For each of the records you want to track in the list, add a List Member record where

a) List Name field points to the new ShortList record that you created

b) Member field points to the record you want to add to the list.

To enforce the constraint that members of the Short list should belong to the related long list you will need to write a filtered lookup on the ShortListMember form such that the lookup view only displays records that belong to the related LongList.
This is a little complicated so let me know if you intend to go this way and I can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sunil. I actually made something like yours yesterday, apart from creating List-Member entities. I made my short list child of the longlist, as every long list may have its own short lists and every short list must have a parent long list.I still will try your solution as well but I think I'm only struggling with the view filter now. I can filter it but for each long list, I have to write a new view. Can I make it work with only relations or do I have to use connections for filtering that stuff? Or if I do it in your way, would only relations work? Thank you again.

Comment: And one more question. How can i trigger a process to create a new record in List-Member entities? I can of course pass the list to the List-Member entity but cannot reach the member record which i added into that list. Also I cannot find a trigger to the process stating that a member is added in the list.

Comment: Actually, connections would work just as well.. A connection would be analogous to the ListMember entity I described above. Basically the ListMember entity is a connection between a list and a record on the list. In fact I wanted to suggest connections as well when I initially answered your question but my answer was getting really long.

Comment: To trigger something when a list member is added to a list you should create a workflow that gets triggered when the List field of the ListMember entity gets changed.

Comment: To filter your view, you need to build FetchXML similar to contact->link-entity->LongList->condition LongList == LongList associated with the current Shortlist. P.S. If you find my answer helpful feel free to upvote it :)

Comment: Thank you. I can't vote you as I'm too new in the site =) 

I'm gonna work on the view stuff as you said but still, I can't trigger the workflow because I have to trigger it from the change in the list actually. I'm have trigger it to add the record to the ListMember entity. You said "To trigger something when a list member is added to a list you should create a workflow that gets triggered when the List field of the ListMember entity gets changed" but I my problem is, I can't change ListMember entity accordingto the addition of the member to the List.

Comment: Now I'm confused.. When exactly do you want the event to trigger and what do you want to do when the event triggers.

Comment: I'll try to explain more simply. I'll add Members to the Lists. When I add them, then there must be a new record in ListMember entity with the name of the list and the name of the member. So, the process which will create the record in the ListMember entity must be triggered when a new Member is added to a List and the process should reach both the Member and List. My problem is, neither when I select List nor Member to trigger a process, I can't either find a trigger like "when a member is added to list" or "when this member is added to a list". Hope I explained well. Thanks for you interest.

Comment: As I understand it, you add a member to a list by creating a new List Member record. So if you want to do some processing when a new member is added to a list you need to trigger a workflow on Create of a List Member record.

Comment: Thanks for all the information Sunil. I managed to make the addition using the connections. Now I'm trying to figure out how to delete or inactivate the records in the ListMember entities.