# CRM Dynamics How to trigger a process when a member is added to a list entity

Tags: process, dynamics-crm-2011

I have 3 entities like Member, List and ListMember. Member and List have many-to-many relationship, as a Member can be added to multiple Lists and naturally a list have multiple Members added to itself. I'm trying to keep the related records of Members and List in the ListMember entity. That is, when a Member is added to a List, then there must be a record created in ListMember entity with the Member and List.

My first question is, is there any automated way to do this, that is, can I define ListMember entity as a many-to-many relationship keeper or something like that?

Second question is, if there isn't such a way, how can I trigger a process which creates records with the Member and List in the ListMember entity each time a Member is added into a List, and how can I reach data from both List and the Member in the process?

For more info about the problem, here is my previous question which reduced the situation into this triggering thing:

[CRM Dynamics How to set short list - long list relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002480/crm-dynamics-how-to-set-short-list-long-list-relationship#)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 basic options when it comes to creating a M:M relationship in CRM:

1. Add the relationship and defining it as M:M will create your ListMemeber Entity for you, and adding a List to a member, or a member to a list will be populated in the ListMember Entity.
2. Roll your own Entity that basically does the same thing.  You can also auto-populate fields on the form by looking up the `regardingojectid`

   regObj = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue();

The regardingobjectid will return the referencing entity that you came from when creating a new entity.  This will allow you to populate the side of the relationship that you came from, so the user just has to select the other entity.

It sounds like you want option 1, so I won't go anymore in-depth on Option 2.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. You're right that I want the first option. So, where can I find that automatically created entity? I can't find it in the entity list in the customization window.

Comment: @ZaferSernikli it's because it's not listed as a true entity.  You can't configure it outside of the relationship.  If you need any other information, you'll have to create your own joining entity.

Comment: So we're back to the option 2. If I am going to use my joining entity, then I need a process to add recods in ListMember entity every time a Member is added in a List. How can I use this action to trigger a process which will add a record to the ListMember entity?

Comment: @ZaferSernikli you wouldn't add a Member to list, you'd create a new ListMember, selecting the Member and the List within the entity.  Then there is no trigger to create.

Comment: Well, you're saying I just have to use the ListMember entity but it's going to be hard for the user to do this stuff then. If I use the method, adding Members to the List, it's really simple as he just click "Add existing Members" button and selects the ones that he wants to add. In your way, he has to select the List and Member for each Member he wants to match with a List; and that's not a practical thing.

Comment: @ZaferSernikli - Use the `regardingobjectid` (See Edit)